# Spring's RestTemplate reads Double instead Long

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have two Spring app, which communicate via REST. In first I have:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/timers")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Long> doJob(){
 return someMap;
}
```

In the second app I'm consuming this service:

```
public Map<String, Long> getMap(){
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  return restTemplate.getForObject(urlToFirst, Map.class);
}
```

But it parse value objects in JSON as Double, not as Long. So, what can I do to force Spring to parse Long here, not double?

My JSON in this communication is:

```
{"1075218":1487581426000}
```

Comment: In background resttemplate uses jackson marshaller; you may use your own serializer and/or deserializer

Comment: But Map, String and Long are standart classes, so it is strange to write own deserializer.

Comment: I think that the default behaviour is: let's convert it in a generic possible value so no error will be generated

Comment: Using class Number on client saved me (but had make my code more ugly)